# How to loop through rows from an imported excel doc and take the string value and use that to name the final image output

Tags: python, for-loop, openpyxl, naming

I want to know how to loop through an excel column and take the str value in each row and use it to the name the final image output. 
Currently I am naming the final images as img1, img2, img3 etc but want to name this with the str value in the rows.

```
final_qr.save(r'C:\ xxxxxxxxxxxxx \img'+ str(i) + '.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty easy with pylightxl, see docs https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

```
import pylightxl as xl

workbook = xl.readxl(‘yourexcelfile.xlsx’)

for cell in workbook.ws(‘Sheet1’).col(1):
    final_qr.save(r'C:\ xxxxxxxxxxxxx \img'+ str(cell) + '.png')
```